# PYTHON: Image.save() not working on Heroku?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, heroku, discord.py

I am trying to host a discord.py bot on Heroku. Everything is working just fine - except for `Image.save()`. This bot utilizes selenium to go to specific web pages and take screenshots, save them locally, upload them to discord, then delete them.

I have gone through my entire screenshot function (literally by adding `print('test 1')` and `print('test 2')` all over my code) and got it down to

`stitched_image.save(save_path)`

where `stitched_image` is an Image type and `save_path` is `/app/Pictures/ss0.png`. It's not even erroring, it just stops. Please, this is driving me crazy and I've been trying to fix this for two days, no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT: is this just something that isn't allowed on Heroku? I'm happy to move on and try (oh god) AWS if this is the case,

Comment: You can avoid saving images locally by using [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). In fact, you should never save them locally if you are just going to delete them anyway.

Comment: "is this just something that isn't allowed on Heroku?"—it's _allowed_, but [don't expect the images to stay where you put them for long](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). It sounds like you're okay with that. Try using a relative path instead of an absolute one (e.g. `Pictures/ss0.png`) since you don't get to decide where Heroku puts your app in the filesystem, and make sure to create the `Pictures` directory first.